# How can I play a guitar-based song on piano?

Tags: guitar, theory, piano, chords, scales

The song in the picture as an example, it’s a guitar-based song, I tried to play these chords on piano and sing but couldn’t feel like it is the same song (Even after I did the transposing) , how can I turn it to a piano version (a new arrangement like many players do on Youtube).

https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-3442feaf90bcb9509065deb29a0ce451?convert_to_webp=true

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the link is dead, and there's not enough information to know what song is being discussed.

Answer (score 3):

That one is actually very straightforward to arrange for piano, as you have so many ways to play each chord, just choose ones that sound good to you.

It doesn't need anything clever - you may just be using an inversion which doesn't match the chord used in the guitar version.

Answer (score 1):

You won't make it sound much like the original, which was most likely written on guitar. Reason being, the strum that the rhythm guitar is using is difficult to emulate on piano.Of course, you can play the melody, bass and lead bits, but you'll never make the piano sound like the guitar strummed here. You may approximate it, with arpeggiated chords, but that's about all.You could play a different version, which is what others may do, and, yes, it changes the feel, even though it would stay in 6/8 and in D. You also would, as Dr. Mayhem suggests, have fun with different chord voicings.